# What is the correct term for a URL such as http://example.com/script?foo=bar?

Tags: url, terminology, uri

I need to refer to URLs such as the one mentioned in the title for my dissertation and I'm not sure what the technical term is (or if one exists).

It's the foo=bar part that I'm particularly interested in as I use it as an indication that a directory traversal vulnerability may be present.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its called the **[querystring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)**

Answer (score 3):

That segment is the *query string*. As a whole it is just an HTTP URI.

Answer (score 1):

A URL with x=y parameters in the querystring is commonly called a **parameterized URL**.